# Ошибка GitLab: Validate branches Cannot Create: This merge request already exists

Tags: gitlab

При попытке отправить запрос на слияние я получаю ошибку:

> The form contains the following error:Validate branches Cannot Create: This merge request already exists: ["название_ветки"]

До этого на слияния была отправлена ветка, имеющая общего родителя с этой.

С Git работать начал совсем недавно. Как решить проблему и в будущем обезопасить себя от подобного?